# CloudDeploy Manipulate Plot

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I made this manipulateble `LogLogPlot`:

```
man = Manipulate[
  LogLogPlot[
   Evaluate[
    Table[(c (4.13*^19 a + 4.13*^19 c) + 
        10^b (1.36*^18 + 
           c (1.36*^18 + 4.15*^16 a + 
              4.15*^16 c)))/(2.05*^17 a + 
        2.05*^17 c + 
        10^b (6.82*^15 + 2.06*^14 a + 
           2.06*^14 c)), {b, 1., 5, 1}]], {a, 10^-3, 
    10^3}, PlotLegends -> Table[ 10^b, {b, 1, 5, 1}]], {{c, 1/100}, 0, .1}]
```

[image]

I want to share this with my colleagues, using multiple manipulation sliders. Things are moving away from the cdf browser plugin, so I thought to use the cloud. However If I  run `CloudDeploy[man]` I get a link with a page showing a red box:
[image]

What can I do to make this work?

Edit: In other Browser I see an error "BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() number type has more than 15 significant digits: 41300000000000000000" as described by kuba

Comment: After a quick look, the reason are big numbers that JS can't handle, don't know how to fix it in general.

Comment: @Kuba, ok I could try to see wether I can rescale the numbers. seems like it sould be below $2^{53}$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As we discovered Cloud's FrontEnd can't handle big numbers so well. Pity because the controller does not really operate in those ranges.

You can only ask WRI Support about this issue, or design your Manipulate in a way that it will work with `Log` values. This gets too cumbersome in general.

Alternatively, I started a toy project for deploying `CloudCDFs` based on custom interface. Your example works well (sometimes I have an issue that ticks are missing but it is Cloud's fault anyway.

So follow installation steps in https://github.com/kubaPod/MVue

and run:

```
Needs@"MVue`"

CloudDeploy[
  MVue["ExportFunction" -> "SVG"] @ Manipulate[
    Plot[
      Evaluate[ Table[
        (c (4.13*^19 a + 4.13*^19 c) + 10^b (1.36*^18 + c (1.36*^18 + 4.15*^16 a + 4.15*^16 c))
        )/(2.05*^17 a + 2.05*^17 c + 10^b (6.82*^15 + 2.06*^14 a + 2.06*^14 c))
      , {b, 1., 5, 1}
      ]]
    , {a, 10^-3, 10^3}
    , PlotLegends -> Table[10^b, {b, 1, 5, 1}]
    ]
  , {{c, 1/100}, 0, .1}
  ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is amazing! One problem I do have with this solution though is when I want to share this.  When I set permissions to `"Public"` or `"rx"` the plot does not seem to load.

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 very strange, it should because `CloudDeploy` options are passed to api function too.